# Wine Installation, seems it's broken with the new fresh Ubuntu 21.4 Realese, caused of some unmet dependencies. Please help

Tags: wine, 21.04

just then I was performing another new Ubuntu 21.04 installation, and today (not this error few weeks ago) I'm going to install Wine and now cannot be possible, because it say that I have the unmet dependencies.So the error by Terminal it's as following:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
winehq-staging: Depends: wine-staging (= 6.10 ~ hirsute-1)
E: Unable to fix problems, there are bad packages blocked.
```

Edit 2 :

to replay to @user535733, I made as following movements (as always but other times never gives me this error):

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

$ wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key

$ sudo apt-key add winehq.key

$ sudo apt install software-properties-common

$ sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -cs) main"

$ sudo apt update

$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

And come out the unmet dependencies error. I have installed Wine other times but I never got this type of error...

If I following the error to install wine-staging instead of winehq-staging (or even wine-stable doesn't change the resaults), with folowing command come out this error:

```
$ sudo apt install wine-staging

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 
libdbus-1-3: i386: It depends on: libsystemd0: i386 but is not installable

libpulse0: i386: Depends: libsystemd0: i386 but is not installable
 
libusb-1.0-0: i386: Depends: libudev1: i386 (> = 183) but is not installable
 
wine-staging-i386: i386: Depends: libudev1: i386 (> = 183) but is not installable
                          
Recommend: libgtk-3-0: i386 but not installable
                          
Recommend: libsane: i386 or
                                      
libsane1: i386 but is not installable

E: Unable to fix problems, there are bad packages blocked.
```

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question should include a link to whatever instructions you were following.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the problem on fresh 21.04 VM. WineHQ have broken dependencies in their repositories for all Wine subversions (*stable*, *devel*, *staging*).

So I would recommend the following:

1. Remove WineHQ repository with

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository -r "deb http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -cs) main"
   ```
2. Install PlayOnLinux with Wine 5.0.3 from official Ubuntu repository by

   ```
   sudo apt-get install playonlinux
   ```
3. Install some application using PlayOnLinux wizard and then change needed Wine version for needed application/wine-prefix only for current user.

Comment: thanks for testing, so seems bad news this. I would like to use the build-in Wine for continue some testing, but in this case i need to wait......

Answer (score 0):

I'm replying by my self in this post, to upgrade to all the community that all the packages blocked, now come out the upgrades and can be possible to proceed the Wine installation without problems.

Thanks for the supports.

Comment: I think this might have been garbled in translation. It's unclear if you are trying to say to upstream Wine packages **do** work now...or if you are trying to say that upstream Wine packages **don't** work now.