# Been trying to install Wine all night and keep getting broken package error

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, wine, dependencies

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and no matter what I try I keep getting a broken package error, and I don't even know what packages are broken. I have the main Wine installed but winehq-stable just won't for me. Dev branch won't install either.

Here is the apt-cache policy wine-devel

```
wine-devel:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7.0.0~hirsute-2
  Version table:
     7.0.0~hirsute-2 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     7.0.0~focal-2 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     7.0~rc6~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     7.0~rc6~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     7.0~rc5~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     7.0~rc5~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     7.0~rc4~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     7.0~rc4~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     7.0~rc3~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     7.0~rc3~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     7.0~rc2~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     7.0~rc2~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     7.0~rc1~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     7.0~rc1~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.23~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.23~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.22~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.22~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.21~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.21~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.20~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.20~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.19~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.19~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.18~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.18~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.17~hirsute-2 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.17~focal-2 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.16~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.16~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.15~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.15~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.14~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.14~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.13~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.13~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.12~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.12~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.11~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.11~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.10~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.10~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.9~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.9~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.8~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.8~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.7~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.7~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.6~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.5~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.4~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.3~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.2~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.1~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.0.0~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.0~rc6~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.0~rc5~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.0~rc4~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.0~rc3~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.0~rc2~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.0~rc1~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.22~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.21~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.20~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.19~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.18~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.17~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.16~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.15~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.14~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.13~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
...
```

There you guys go, thanks.
Whenever I tried sudo apt install wine-devel=7.0.0~hirsute-2, this happened.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-devel : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.33) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 is to be installed
              Depends: wine-devel-i386 (= 7.0.0~hirsute-2)
              Depends: wine-devel-amd64 (= 7.0.0~hirsute-2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So this is apt-cache policy libc6

```
  Installed: 2.31-0ubuntu9.2
  Candidate: 2.31-0ubuntu9.2
  Version table:
 *** 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.31-0ubuntu9 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

And this is apt-cache policy wine-devel-i386

```
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7.0.0~hirsute-2
  Version table:
     7.0.0~hirsute-2 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
     7.0.0~focal-2 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     7.0~rc6~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
     7.0~rc6~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     7.0~rc5~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
     7.0~rc5~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     7.0~rc4~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
     7.0~rc4~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     7.0~rc3~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
     7.0~rc3~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     7.0~rc2~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
     7.0~rc2~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     7.0~rc1~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
     7.0~rc1~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.23~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
     6.23~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.22~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
     6.22~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.21~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
     6.21~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.20~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
     6.20~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.19~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
     6.19~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.18~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
     6.18~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.17~hirsute-2 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
     6.17~focal-2 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.16~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
     6.16~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.15~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
     6.15~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.14~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
     6.14~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.13~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
     6.13~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.12~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
     6.12~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.11~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
     6.11~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.10~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
     6.10~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.9~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
     6.9~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.8~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
     6.8~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.7~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main i386 Packages
     6.7~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.6~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.5~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.4~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.3~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.2~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.1~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.0.0~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.0~rc6~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.0~rc5~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.0~rc4~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.0~rc3~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.0~rc2~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     6.0~rc1~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     5.22~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     5.21~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     5.20~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     5.19~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     5.18~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     5.17~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     5.16~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     5.15~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     5.14~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     5.13~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     5.12~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     5.11~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     5.10~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     5.9~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     5.8~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     5.7~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
```

Here is apt-cache policy wine-devel-amd64

```
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7.0.0~hirsute-2
  Version table:
     7.0.0~hirsute-2 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     7.0.0~focal-2 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     7.0~rc6~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     7.0~rc6~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     7.0~rc5~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     7.0~rc5~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     7.0~rc4~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     7.0~rc4~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     7.0~rc3~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     7.0~rc3~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     7.0~rc2~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     7.0~rc2~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     7.0~rc1~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     7.0~rc1~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.23~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.23~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.22~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.22~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.21~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.21~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.20~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.20~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.19~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.19~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.18~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.18~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.17~hirsute-2 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.17~focal-2 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.16~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.16~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.15~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.15~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.14~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.14~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.13~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.13~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.12~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.12~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.11~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.11~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.10~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.10~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.9~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.9~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.8~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.8~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.7~hirsute-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 Packages
     6.7~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.6~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.5~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.4~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.3~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.2~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.1~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.0.0~focal-1 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.0~rc6~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.0~rc5~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.0~rc4~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.0~rc3~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.0~rc2~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     6.0~rc1~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.22~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.21~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.20~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.19~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.18~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.17~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.16~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.15~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.14~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.13~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.12~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.11~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.10~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.9~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.8~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.7~focal 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Here is sudo apt update again

```
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                                 
Hit:3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                                                                                                                                          
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                                                                                                               
Hit:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                  
Hit:6 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                             
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybolic/vineyard-testing/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                        
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                          
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]                                         
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease        
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [40.6 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [282 kB]                                 
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [66.3 kB]
Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybolic/vineyard-testing/ubuntu focal Release                              
  404  Not Found [IP: removed 80]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]               
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [364 kB]                                                                      
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [944 B]
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [8,000 B]
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [12.2 kB]
Err:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu focal Release                           
  404  Not Found [IP: removed 80]
Reading package lists... Done                                                                  
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybolic/vineyard-testing/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

---

Here is the apt update line.

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]     
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                         
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]      
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Fetched 336 kB in 2s (166 kB/s)                                   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

Here is the apt install wine line

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
wine is already the newest version (5.0-3ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I already removed all my repositories though.

Comment: Format the output as code (put them between three ticks `). Then you can still post them.

Comment: Alright, how did I do that? And is that connected to the "broken packages" message?

Comment: @GarethTV  `E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybolic/vineyard-testing/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file` you have to fix this error too. remove this ppa it has no packages for focal. an d why have you add winehq repo for different releases?

Comment: This is not a forum. Don't include SOLVED or the solution inside the question.

Comment: @Someone My bad, I'm used to doing that lol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all I agree with Someone that two 404 repositories should be removed from the system first by

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:cybolic/vineyard-testing
sudo apt-get update
```

Then I'm sorry to inform you, but WineHQ developers have broken repositories [again](https://askubuntu.com/a/1346394/66509). I have just tested both Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and 21.10 in fresh Docker containers and I can't install any of `winehq-stable`, `winehq-devel` and `winehq-staging` here.

So you have to remove these problematic repositories by

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'
sudo add-apt-repository -r 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ hirsute main'
sudo add-apt-repository -r 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ impish main'
```

Then run `sudo apt-get update` and afterwards install wine by

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Or better - PlayOnLinux by

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Then install some application using PlayOnLinux wizard and then change needed Wine version for needed application/wine-prefix only for current user. To manage Wine versions in PlayOnLinux visit its *Tools* → *Manage Wine version* menu and select available Wine versions from here:

[image: PlayOnLinux, Wine versions]

Comment: Can I use another program that I already had installed on PlayOnLinux? An exe portable file actually

Comment: You can install `wine` package from official *focal* repository. I updated my answer above.

Comment: Latest version of Wine is always available from PlayOnLinux for any specific application.

Comment: For our smart-minded down-voters. Some third-party repository, say WineHQ is broken. We can't do anything with this. There is an alternative method, I presented it here. If one of you have a good will - please report bug to the repository owners and ask them to fix it. PlayOnLinux solution is fully-functional alternative.

Comment: Honestly this is the route I'm going, it seems to be a good way to get around all this Wine install mess.

Comment: Your answer is pretty much all good. I don't why someone will downvote. It's good in my opinion.

Comment: Same, seems all good to me. Thanks guys

Comment: @Norbert it is not broken, but if you bound the repo in  for different releases like Gareth TV did, when apt is in trouble.

Comment: @nobody Yes, that's what I think too... I posted an answer a few minutes ago, but I deleted it as it doesn't seem as good as N0rbert's, moreover, OP said it didn't work. I've  undeleted it for you to see.

Comment: Yeah, it still gave me the broken package error.

Comment: What's the error? Is it exactly the same?

Comment: @nobody It is actually broken. I confirmed this on fresh empty docker container with only one 3rd-party repository added - WineHQs. There are no more any other 3rd-party repositories added. If I write something, I prove it by testing first.

Comment: @Someone yes the error was the exact same, I don't know what was causing it but what N0bert is saying makes sense

Comment: @GarethTV Please edit your question again and add output of `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install wine` to it. You can remove obsolete outputs from it to keep it relevant.

Comment: @N0rbert Is using `apt-get` better than `apt`? You always use `apt-get` in your answers, any specific reason?

Comment: @Someone It is probably a habit more than anything else. I like to distinguish between `apt-get` and `apt-cache`. It may be a reason.

Comment: @GarethTV It seems that problem is solved. I do not see any errors.

Comment: Alright, does the individual version of Wine come with PlayOnLinux? Like can I just right click a exe and launch it with Wine?

Comment: PlayOnLinux will install default wine 5.0.3 version. For more comprehensive tasks you can use Install, Install non-listed application, follow wizard, and specify newer version from here. See https://wiki.playonlinux.com/index.php/Manual_Installations .

Comment: then it have to be broken shortly. `wine --version
wine-7.0`