# installing wine on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, wine

when I am trying to install wine HQ on my machine it's showing an error
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 7.0.0.0~impish-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

[here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5Aoe.png)
please help me,
thank you

Comment: Please don't post images of text, copy&paste the command output to your question as text and format it as a code block.

Comment: Use the official repositories. The repository provided by WineHQ team creates issues. Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/1389755/124466

Comment: thank you for the help it worked